# Combining OnTouchListener and OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Even though I checked some threads, I'm having problems to use both the OnTouchListener and the OnClickListener inside of a fragment.

Custom class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Gestures implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector = null;
    public Gestures()
    {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        boolean res = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return res;
    }
    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 50;
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            onLongClick();
            super.onLongPress(motionEvent);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent1, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            boolean result = false;
            try
            {
                float differenceX = motionEvent2.getX() - motionEvent1.getX();
                float differenceY = motionEvent2.getY() - motionEvent1.getY();

                if (Math.abs(differenceX) < Math.abs(differenceY))
                {
                    if (Math.abs(differenceY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                    {
                        if (differenceY > 0)
                        {
                            result = onSwipeBottom();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = nothing();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    public boolean nothing()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onSwipeTop()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onSwipeBottom()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onLongClick()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener
{
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayoutOne, constraintLayoutTwo;
    @Override public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        constraintLayoutOne = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_one); // Link variable to ID
        constraintLayoutTwo = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_two); // Link variable to ID
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_one).setOnClickListener(this);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_two).setOnClickListener(this);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_one).setOnTouchListener(this);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_two).setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View fragment1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false); // Link view and layout
        return fragment1;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.constraint_layout_one:
            case R.id.constraint_layout_two:
                view.setOnTouchListener(new Gestures()
                {
                    public boolean onSwipeTop()
                    {
                        showToast("swiped up");
                        return false;
                    }
                    public boolean onSwipeBottom()
                    {
                        showToast("swiped down");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.constraint_layout_one)
        {
            showToast("button one clicked");
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.constraint_layout_two)
        {
            showToast("button two clicked");
        }
    }
    public void showToast(String text)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Generate toast message
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.CENTER, 0, -1); // Change y-Position of toast a bit
        toast.show(); // Show toast for 4 seconds
    }
}
```

The two problems:

1) 
When I start the app, the swipes don't work. Nothing happens when I swipe.
I have to perform 2 swipes to get it to work.
After that, I can swipe as often as I want.

2)
The clicks only work one time.
After the first click, no further clicks get recognized anymore (for the clicked view)
Same happens when I do two swipes - no clicks anymore.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried something completely different. -> onInterceptTouchEvent 
I created a helper class named RootView:

```
import android.content.Context; 
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import android.view.MotionEvent; 
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class RootLayout extends ConstraintLayout
{
    public RootLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
    public RootLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }
    public RootLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyleAttribute)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttribute);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Inside of my xml file, I changed the ConstraintLayout to the RootLayout:

```
<com.example.testSwipeApp.RootLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.10"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</com.example.testSwipeApp.RootLayout>
```

The fragment1.java looks like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayoutOne, constraintLayoutTwo;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View fragment1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false); // Link view and layout
        constraintLayoutOne = fragment1.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_one); // Link variable to ID
        constraintLayoutTwo = fragment1.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_two); // Link variable to ID
        fragment1.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_one).setOnClickListener(this);
        fragment1.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_two).setOnClickListener(this);

        fragment1.setOnTouchListener(new Gestures()
        {
            public boolean onSwipeTop()
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Swiped up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
            public boolean onSwipeBottom()
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Swiped down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return fragment1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.constraint_layout_one:
            case R.id.constraint_layout_two:
                showToast("clicked");
            break;
        }
    }
    public void showToast(String text)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Generate toast message
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.CENTER, 0, -1); // Change y-Position of toast a bit
        toast.show(); // Show toast for 4 seconds
    }
}
```

The problem:
Clicks don't get accepted anymore.
Even though this version works worse, I prefer this way rather than the old one.

Any help will be appreciated!